# Do we have dispatcher servlet in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As per my understanding when a spring application starts, request goes to dispatcher Servlet and from there it gets dispatched to respective controllers. In spring mvc we define Dispatcher Servlet in web.xml file. I want to know is the process is same for Spring boot application also means application request goes to dispatcher Servlet and from there it gets dispatched to respective controllers. 
And if it is where are we defining our dispatcher Servlet in Spring boot application?

Answer (score 3):

yes spring boot uses dispatcher servlet and it is located in DispatcherServlet

fully qualified name of class:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

in normal java web application web.xml is the source of declaring main components and structure definition of web application like servlets , filters and so on, in other words it's meta data of our web application that the servlet containers like tomcat uses to know how run the application.

in spring boot as mentioned above, dispatcher servelet is declared inside DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration

fully qualified name of class:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatcher Servlet` is a part of 'Spring MVC'.

Strictly speaking, Spring boot application doesn't necessarily has to run Spring MVC, although in most of practical cases it does.

So, If spring boot application runs spring mvc there is certainly a DispatcherServlet exists under the hood.